# Pause and Restore Async Task in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an Asynctask which is running continuously to get the geo-coordiantes with a specific interval of time. Its running till the user exit the activity, but i have a pause button which will pause the asynctask and a resume button which will resume the asynctask from the position it has paused. So how to do it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SomI.png

Comment: you should be using a Fused Location Provider, it does all of this automatically. you set how often to receive a new location, and call simple `connect()` and `disconnect()` methods to 'pause' it

Comment: *Asynctask ... to get the geo-coordiantes* ... interesting, I wana see this, it had to be extremely bad design(is there a getLastKnownLocation involved?, that's is not how we get coords updates) ... back on the topic ... **`AsyncTask` is for doing some job on background and  return ... not for "infinitive loops"** so "pausing an AsyncTask" doesn't make sens

Comment: Actually the loop is not for getting geo-coordiantes. its for a count down timer with a circular fill progress bar. for example .if i set the timer to 10 sec then the progress and timer will countdown to 10sec den again for next 10sec till the user exit the app. So i put both the countdown timer and progress update inside aysynctask. So now when i want to click on the pause button i want to pause the timer and progress with getting dynamic locations from onlocation change method. and when i will click on the resume button it will resume from the position where its get paused.

Comment: Cancel the task when pausing, and create a new task when resuming. You can persist the current progress of the task when you cancel it, and pass that to the new task if you don't want it to reset.

Comment: Thank You for the support . I got your point. But will it not make a performance issue??

Comment: I have posted a screenshot of the app

Comment: unless you are doing large amounts of setup in the creation of the async task (you should not be in this usage) then it will make zero performance difference.

Comment: Ok... can you please have a look on the screenshot of my app i have posted now..

Answer (score 0):

you should know that AsyncTask is usually used is for tasks that take long time to be completed, tasks that are considered restricted on the main thread.
thats why its used in http connections to servers for example. 
Iv also read that method doInBackground cant access the UI, so when you update the progress bar from inside the method it wont work, instead you can access UI from onPreExecute and onProgressUpdate as well as onPostExecute methods.

this may help you understand exactly how AsyncTask works: 
https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/

and this:
http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html#.Vjs3QrcrLcs

Answer (score 0):

I had worked on a ditto same application for one client few months back. Async Task is a really bad idea to get loacation; A Really bad implementation indeed.

I was using in the following way:
-1 Creating my own LocationListener 
-2 Creating my own Service which gets a hold of this LocationListener as long as I have my context registered to the LocationListener and keeps returning the LatLng or just save them in Background. I had to upload to a server.
-3 Removing updates from LocationListener inside service and killing service when done.
-4 Repeat when needed.

let me know if you still need detailed code.

**PS [Read this about Async Task](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/06/21/the-hidden-pitfalls-of-asynctask/) if you still continue with your implementation.**